# Function called without being told to

Tags: python, function, testing

Newish to python, working on  a text adventure, testing out the use of functions.

```
def cell1():
    loop = 1
    while loop == 1:
        print("ONE")
        cave1 = input()
        if cave1 == ("end?"):
            print("\nthis should end program")
            loop = 0
            break
        elif cave1 == ("TWO"):
            global testvar
            testvar = 1
            option1()
        else:
            print("INVALID")

def option1():
    print("TWO")
    loop = 1
    while loop == 1:
        print("test1 definition")
        print (testvar)
        test1 = input()
        if test1 == ("ONE"):
            print("you pick up the cheese")
            loop = 0
            cell1()
        elif test1 == ("THREE"):
            option2()
        else:
            print("INVALID")

def option2():
    print("THREE")
    loop = 1
    while loop == 1:
        print("This is option 3")
        test2 = input()
        if test2 == ("ONE"):
            print("testering2")
            cell1()
        elif test2 == ("TWO"):
            global testvar
            testvar = 2014
            option1()
        else:
            print("INVALID")
run = True
while run == (True):
    print ("testing 123")
    cell1()
    print("restart about to activate")
    cont = input("Restart? ")

    if (cont) != "yes":
       break
```

This program should allow you to go between options (what would be rooms) and eventually in cell1, the program should be end-able.

if the program is run and "end?" is typed as the first input, the program goes into the continue bit at the bottom, however, if you go between the 'rooms' then back to cell1, typing "end?" will call option 2.

Ive had a look around and it is still baffling me, am i ding something wrong?

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Hint: if cell1 calls option1, and option1 calls cell1, and then cell1 ends and option1 ends, the first cell1 call will still be running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that the issue you're having is because you don't always `break` out of the loop in one function when you call another function. For instance, if your entries were `TWO`, `ONE` then `end?`, you'd find yourself still in the `cell1` loop. That's because when the inner call to `cell1` returns, the control flow of the program goes back to where that function was called from, which is `option1`, since `loop` is now `0`, the loop ends and `option1` returns, to the outer call to `cell1`, where the loop is still running.

Unless you want the game you're designing to have a tree structure, where you can return to where you came from with different semantics than moving to some other place, I'd suggest using a different architecture. Rather than each of your functions calling the next function when appropriate, return that function instead. Then you'd write a single top level loop that calls the function. Here's an example where the function to be called by the top level loop is saved in a variable named `state`:

```
def cell1():
    print("In cell1!")
    while True:
        choice = input("pick 'ONE' or 'TWO' (or type 'quit' to exit):")
        if choice == "ONE":
            return option1
        elif choice == "TWO":
            return option2
        elif choice == "quit":
            return None
        else:
            print("I'm sorry, I didn't understand that.")

def option1():             # these other two functions are very basic in my example
    print("In option1!")   # but you can make them as complex as you want
    return option2

def option2():
    print("in option2!")
    return cell1

def control_loop(initial_state=cell1):
    state = initial_state
    while state is not None:
        state = state() # the next state is the return value of the previous state
```

Comment: Okay so ive added break after i call a function, which should mean only one function ever runs at a time right? I want movement to be like that in real life, where you can move anywhere as long as physically possible, not like a tree where you have to retrace your steps. Will just breaking after each function call be enough?

Comment: Well, that will mostly work, since it will make the outer functions return right away, rather than looping more. But you'll still be building up a stack of function calls for no good reason. I suggest a single-level architecture in my answer, though there are probably other approaches that could work just as well.

Answer (score 1):

The reason `"end?"` only quits for the player when they are within the first cell is because you're only checking for that input therein. The execution contained within `option1()` and `option2()` doesn't affect the execution of `cell1()`. You're not returning anything from your option functions, nor are you changing a sentinel value.

So, there's two basic ways you could go about this.

First, you could return a value from your functions:

```
if option1() == "END":
    break
```

Or, you could alter your while loop:

```
# is_running is defined globally
while is_running:
```

And then just set `is_running` to `False` in any of your methods whenever the user types `"end?"`. That'd probably be the easiest way with the design you're using now.

I'm sure you can tell, though, that in general your program is going to get exponentially more complex as you add more rooms and your function calls get further nested.

Comment: Okay so ive added break after i call a function, which should mean only one function ever runs at a time right? I want movement to be like that in real life, where you can move anywhere as long as physically possible, not like a tree where you have to retrace your steps. Will just breaking after each function call be enough? –

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are getting deeper and deeper within nested functions. For example, changing

```
if test1 == ("ONE"):
        print("you pick up the cheese")
        loop = 0
        cell1()
```

to

```
if test1 == ("ONE"):
        print("you pick up the cheese")
        loop = 0
        break
```

will allow you to run your program, enter room two, go back to room one, and `"end?"` will work properly. This won't fix your issues completely though because there is a similar problem where when you go from two to three where if you simply changed

```
if test2 == ("ONE"):
        print("testering2")
        cell1()
```

to

```
if test2 == ("ONE"):
        print("testering2")
        break
```

it would break the current function and go back into `option1()` (if you run your program, go to room two, then to room three, then back to one) where `"end?"` doesn't do anything. Hopefully this gets you on the right track.

Comment: Okay so ive added break after i call a function, which should mean only one function ever runs at a time right? I want movement to be like that in real life, where you can move anywhere as long as physically possible, not like a tree where you have to retrace your steps. Will just breaking after each function call be enough? –